# htaccess redirect pages to specific subdomain

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

Lets say I have a page at: **foobar.com/application.php**

I want any reference to foobar.com/application.php to redirect as www.foobar.com/application.php. I only want that rule to apply to the application.php page.

xyz.foobar.com/page1.php would not redirect.
xyz.foobar.com/application.php would redirect to www.foobar.com/application.php.

(any subdomain except www).foorbar.com/application.php would redirect to www.

How can I form a htaccess rule that says when the application.php page is accessed to check the subdomain and if it's not www., then make it www.?

**Examples for application.php page**

1. www.foobar.com/application.php  **would NOT redirect since it is www**
2. abc.foobar.com/application.php  **would redirect to www.**
3. xyz.foobar.com/application.php  **would redirect to www.**
4. whatever.foobar.com/application.php  **would redirect to www.**
5. anything.foobar.com/application.php  **would redirect to www.**
6. **(anything here EXCEPT www)**.foobar.com/application.php  **would redirect to www.**

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^xyz.foobar.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /application\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.foobar.com/$1 [NC,R,L]
```

Comment: But wouldn't that only apply to xyz.foobar.com?? I need the rule to fire if xyz is anything except www.